# Scene from sci-fi movie where bald evil-doers in silver costumers laugh hysterically

Tags: story-identification

There is a popular scene from a movie where the bald evil guys are laughing hysterically. They are dressed in silvery costumes and (I think) standing in front of a big screen or so.

The scene itself is used in many memes and jokes.

What is the name of the movie?

Comment: *"Pretty old"*. How dare you, Sir. How very dare you.

Comment: Its from the same year that I was finishing high school ... so yes - it classifies as "pretty old" :). Honestly I thought that it is actually from a much older movie.

Comment: I feel old now! First thing I thought of was Austin Powers,  but your 'film is in black and white' comment threw me!

Comment: Honestly looks like I'm confusing this with the (imaginary) 1930 series of Captain Proton which is actually part of ST: Voyager :)

Comment: @vap78 - My first thought was Ming from the old black-and-white Flash Gordon serials, but that isn't used in any memes that I know of. He did have a tendency to laugh maniacally, though, which is what Dr. Chaotica on "Captain Proton" was inspired by.

Comment: Was trying to remember if there was a point in This Island Earth where they are standing in front of the viewer laughing. Now I see it's Austin Powers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're referring to the '*Threaten the UN*' scene from [Austin Powers: International Man of Mystery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin_Powers_(film_series)).

It's not a black and white film, but the colours are definitely muted in this particular scene.

Answer (score 4):

I assume we all want to watch it, it's right at the very end.

For some reason, only available in Spanish.

Comment: El Capitan Protoné!